# Div overlaps the div above (flex), how can I fix this?

Tags: html, flexbox, overlap

I'm trying to place a div under another div that I used to place three columns using flex property:

```html
            <div class="info-container">
            <div class="column">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione,
                    earum quibusdam a voluptatem nostrum aliquid?
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <h2>lorem ipsum</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est dolorem
                    illo, consectetur hic quo consequatur in, quisquam doloribus fugit
                    ab voluptatibus velit saepe, perspiciatis placeat officiis. Id
                    quisquam velit deleniti!
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa eos
                    nihil at quod adipisci voluptatum sed vel aut est nesciunt non
                    corporis inventore, deserunt eveniet!
                </p>
            </div>
```

```css
.info-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 1.2rem;
    display: flex;
}

.column {
    flex: 33.33%;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 224px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And here is the div I want to place under of this div:

```html
    <div class="quote-container">
    <p>Felix, qui potuit rerum cognoscere causas.</p>
    <h3>-Vergilius, Georgica, 2, 490</h3>
    </div>
```

```css
.quote-container {
    background-color: #2c3e4f;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 24px 28px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

But when I shrink the size of the page, div just simply overlaps the div above.

[Here's the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUYfB.png)

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

I tried `margin-top` or `height` properties but nothing has changed.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve]

Comment: Hello. I edited the post. I hope that helps to clarify my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have hard-coded the height of your `.column` class to `224px`.  At lower screen widths, 224px is not sufficient to contain the text within the columns, so the text is overflow out the bottom of the column.  There are many ways to fix/change this, depending on your desired end outcome, but the simplest is to apply `overflow: hidden` to your `.column` class.

I would also recommend familiarizing yourself with the Developer Tools in the browser of your choice, specifically the "Elements" tab (in Chrome/Edge), or the "Inspector" tab (in Firefox).  Usually they can be accessed by pressing F12, and can make debugging things like this extremely easy, saving you the hassle of putting together a StackOverflow question and having to wait for someone to help you.

```css
.info-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 1.2rem;
    display: flex;
}

.column {
    flex: 33.33%;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 224px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.quote-container {
    background-color: #2c3e4f;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 24px 28px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-container">
            <div class="column">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione,
                    earum quibusdam a voluptatem nostrum aliquid?
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <h2>lorem ipsum</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est dolorem
                    illo, consectetur hic quo consequatur in, quisquam doloribus fugit
                    ab voluptatibus velit saepe, perspiciatis placeat officiis. Id
                    quisquam velit deleniti!
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa eos
                    nihil at quod adipisci voluptatum sed vel aut est nesciunt non
                    corporis inventore, deserunt eveniet!
                </p>
            </div>
  </div>
  <div class="quote-container">
    <p>Felix, qui potuit rerum cognoscere causas.</p>
    <h3>-Vergilius, Georgica, 2, 490</h3>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, and I appreciate your effort to answer this question. Will try to do better next time!